How to install boinc_client Docker on Synology
I'm having an hard time trying to install boinc_client Docker on my Synology.
After having downloaded the latest image through the Synology Docker I launch the image and I use the default setting bridge

I tune a bit the CPU and the Memory and I let all other settings as default:

I keep the port as the default one:

I set a folder in my volume:

Now the container is created and it's up and running on my Synology at port 31416

But if I try to connect to it:
404 Not Found
nginx


What am I doing wrong?
On the official documentation is not written what is the default web page for the boinc_client.
I believe the root cause is overall the network setup but I tried with or without bridge; I tried setting different port with HTTP/HTTPS; I also tried setting the host as the IP address of the Synology. Nothing seems working.

Have you try to set something in Local port?

What should I set @RomeoNinov?

Some port, for example 8000. And use this port when accessing the service

It didn't work @RomeoNinov. I put a bounty. Can you try to install the boinc docker on your end and see if you face the same problem? You don't need a NAS for that, you can try on your PC I think. The problem you'll face will be the same

You don't have complete mapping.  You need to assign a local port (perhaps the same as docker 31416?) to your docker port 31416.
